# Assigning a Pointer to a NativeInt causes E2010 Incompatible types

Tags: pointers, delphi, delphi-xe7

Assigning a `Pointer` to a `NativeInt` variable causes an E2010 on compiling:

```
var
  Test : string;
  Ptr : Pointer;
  LocTag : NativeInt;
begin
  Test := 'Hello World';

  Ptr := @Test;
  LocTag := Ptr;
end;
```

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(34): E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeInt' and
> 'Pointer'

I've read the `Pointer` [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Pointer), in particular:

> The size of a pointer depends on the operating system and/or the
> processor. On 32-bit platforms, a pointer is stored on 4 bytes as a
> 32-bit address. On 64-bit platforms, a pointer is stored on 8 bytes as
> a 64-bit address.

And the `NativeInt` [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.NativeInt), in particular:

> NativeInt represents a subset of the integer numbers. The range of
> NativeInt depends on the current platform. On 32-bit platforms,
> NativeInt is equivalent to the Integer type. On 64-bit platforms,
> NativeInt is equivalent to the Int64 type.
>
> The size of NativeInt is equivalent to the size of the pointer on the
> current platform

Why does the assignment cause the E2010 error?

Is a typecast (`Tag := NativeInt(Ptr);`) the right solution?

Comment: Although a bit off-topic, it might be worth pointing out that, in practice, you seldom need to use `@S` of a string `S`. It is much more common to be interested in `PChar(S)`, which is the same thing as `@S[1]` unless `S` is empty.

Comment: One more off-topic note: If S is a string, then @S and PChar(S) have totally different values. Strings are actually implemented by a record with a few fields. One is the pointer to the first character of the string or nil of the string is empty. @S returns a pointer to the record while PChar(S) returns the field in the record that point to the character (nil is empty string or @S[1] if not empty).

Comment: @fpiette: Actually, that description is not accurate. A string variable is a pointer. Iff the string is non-empty, this points to the first char of the string heap object. Before this first char, you have some metadata about the string: length, refcount, and codepage. `@S` is the address of the pointer. `PChar(S)` is the address of the first char of the string heap object. If `S` is the empty string, the variable is the `nil` pointer. ...

Comment: (cont.) Here's [an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848158/282848) and here's the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Long_String_Types).

Comment: Isn't the real problem that the string is destroyed when the function returns, and now `Tag` holds a stale pointer.

Comment: @David: Did you see that `Tag` is a local variable in this case?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand If we are going to take this code literally, then we can just delete it, and nobody could ever tell the difference. But the name `Tag` is something of a tell hinting at what the underlying intent is.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to guess the OP's intentions; it is perfectly plausible that the above code isn't exactly what the OP is using in his/her real project. Therefore I just focused on the Q "how to assign a pointer to a `NativeInt`".

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sure, and that is perfectly reasonable, and it's the answer to the question asked. Which is why I wrote this aside in a comment.

Comment: Just for precisation: In the example `Tag` has been deliberately defined as local variable. Anyhow the variable's name may be misleading so I've updated the question changing the name to `LocTag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the assignment cause the E2010 error?

Because an integer and a pointer isn't exactly the same thing. A pointer is something that points to a location in your memory; an integer need not do that (even if it happens to have the same size as a pointer). This is about type safety and making sure you don't make mistakes. By using an explicit cast (which you are forced to do), you tell the compiler, anyone reading your code, and yourself, that you know what you are doing.

> Is a typecast (`Tag := NativeInt(Ptr);`) the right solution?

Yes, that's exactly the right thing to do. It is also perfectly safe, because the width of the (`NativeInt`) integer is equal to the width of a pointer.

Comment: (Well, it is "perfectly safe" if you don't do anything stupid with the integer, like dividing it by two, converting the quotient to a `PCardinal`, and attempting to write the cardinal `$AABBCCDD` to this location.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is a typecast (Tag := NativeInt(Ptr);) the right solution?

It will work but I think it is better to use the type `UIntPtr` which has been defined to represents an unsigned integer whose value is a pointer.
`UIntPtr` is used to work with pointers as unsigned integers.

If you look at `UIntPtr` definition, it is an alias to `NativeUInt`.

There is also an `IntPtr` which is an alias to `NativeInt`. This obviously work as well.

Using `UIntPtr` is more clear than anything else and more appropriate if you later use the variable to do pointer arithmetic. This avoid unexpected results when the pointer point to high memory (Above 2GB in the 32 bits address space) because in that case the integer becomes negative.

Comment: On the other hand, the VCL's `Tag` property is of type `NativeInt`.

Comment: +1 Very interesting, I didn't know the `IntPtr`/`UIntPtr` types. Like Andreas said, I'm wondering why the `Tag` property is declared as `NativeInt` (Maybe because it's not necessarily meant to be used as a Pointer only)

Comment: @Fabrizio actually, the Tag property could be any datatype that has the correct size or even larger size. The data type only matters when you want to do something with the data. Tag property value has to be cast to the correct data type as soon as you want to do some computing or use. One must make distinction between storage and computing. For storage, anything which has a size equal or larger to what is required will do. For computing it depends on the computing you want to do (I include dereferencing a pointer into the computing class).